# How do I disable front-end assets compilation in Play 2.5?

Tags: playframework, gulp, sbt, playframework-2.5

I'm using Play Framework 2.5.1 to create an app, and I want to use Gulp instead of SBT for compiling and minifying front-end stuff. Is there a way for me to disable the automatic recompilation on `activator ~run`, so I can still keep JS and Less under `app\assets`, but instead use Gulp for building the front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My configuration:

```
disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin).settings(
       ....    
         watchSources := (watchSources.value
           --- baseDirectory.value / "app" ** "*"
           --- baseDirectory.value / "public" ** "*").get,
         cleanFiles <+= baseDirectory { base => base / "src" / "main" / "public" }
       )
```

- remove app/public from watch
- clean public directory